# SELECT on column using LINQ with an aggregate function

Tags: c#, linq

I'm tring to create a dataset that is only the StatusID from the tbBreadCrumb table after the row that is the max BreadCrumbID is selected but not sure how to do it. Basically, I only want to return StatusID to JSON but I'm getting red underline saying: "int does not contain a definition set for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' could you be missing an assembly?"

Here's my code:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static object getMaxBreadCrumbByProjectID(int id)
    {
        using (dbPSREntities5 myEntities = new dbPSREntities5())
        {
            var thisProject = myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.ProjectID == id).Max(x => x.BreadCrumbID);

            var columns = thisProject.Select(x => new { x.StatusID }).ToList(); <--- this has the red underline and error message.

            return columns;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Max` returning your Maximum `BreadCrumbId` which is an integer.Try this:

```
var id = myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.ProjectID == id).Max(x => x.BreadCrumbID);
var columns = myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.BreadCrumbID == id)
                                      .Select(x => x.StatusID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

As the error is trying to tell you, `thisProject` is already a number.

`Max()` returns the highest value, not a collection.